# Not able to get the required recommended product through RichRelevance SDK for Android

Tags: android, e-commerce

Utils.GuestUserID=sharedPref.getSharedPref(getResources().getString(R.string.guest_user));
        ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration=new ClientConfiguration("hjsd767443","gdfg63476473");
        clientConfiguration.setUserId(Utils.GuestUserID);
        clientConfiguration.setSessionId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        RichRelevance.init(this, clientConfiguration);

```
    RichRelevance.setLoggingLevel(RRLog.VERBOSE);

    PlacementsRecommendationsBuilder placementsRecommendationsBuilder=new PlacementsRecommendationsBuilder();
    placementsRecommendationsBuilder.setProductIds(IDProduct);

    Placement placement = new Placement(Placement.PlacementType.ITEM, "Item page.recs_1mw");
    RichRelevance.buildRecommendationsForPlacements(placement)
            // Attach a callback
            .setCallback(new Callback<PlacementResponseInfo>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(PlacementResponseInfo result) {
                    PlacementResponse placement = result.getPlacements().get(0);
                    RecommendedProduct product = placement.getRecommendedProducts().get(0);

                    product.trackClick();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(com.richrelevance.Error error) {
                    Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                }
            })
                    // Execute the request
            .execute();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utils.GuestUserID=sharedPref.getSharedPref(getResources().getString(R.string.guest_user));
        com.richrelevance.ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration=new com.richrelevance.ClientConfiguration("gdhg76476437gh","hfdjj627642547");
        clientConfiguration.setUserId(Utils.GuestUserID);
        clientConfiguration.setSessionId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        clientConfiguration.setEndpoint(Endpoints.PRODUCTION, true);
        RichRelevance.init(this, clientConfiguration);
Placement placement = new Placement(Placement.PlacementType.ITEM, "recs_1mw");
        PlacementsRecommendationsBuilder placementsRecommendationsBuilder=new PlacementsRecommendationsBuilder();
        placementsRecommendationsBuilder.setPlacements(placement);
        placementsRecommendationsBuilder.setProductIds(IDProduct);

```
    placementsRecommendationsBuilder.setCallback(new Callback<PlacementResponseInfo>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(PlacementResponseInfo placementResponseInfo) {
            PlacementResponse placement = placementResponseInfo.getPlacements().get(0);
            Log.e("placement rich:",placement.toString());
            RecommendedProduct product = placement.getRecommendedProducts().get(0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Error error) {

        }
    }).execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is in the Placement setup:

```
Placement placement = new Placement(Placement.PlacementType.ITEM, "Item page.recs_1mw");
```

should become

```
Placement placement = new Placement(Placement.PlacementType.ITEM, "recs_1mw");
```

As you are already specifying the PageType/PlacementType with the first argument.

Comment: Still I have same problem. It is not working for me. I am getting this result only

Comment: {"status":"ok","rcs":"dG4FwbGRgPAQBJCEyF7OAbnjoQPbEOFnDMzU-t0N4T13L1s1-kAkd5HxwXoTuYtAnyGzzuX-nmusaYtUolhoEmUVAtIPjpDEnA"}